# Get Languages chosen for publish in publish:end event

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I made an event handler for the publish:end event - I'm able to get which item is being published - how do I get the languages the user chose in the publish options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out - actually the publish:end event hits once for every language - and you get get the language that is being published by doing `EventArgs[0].Options.Language`